# Can you suggest me free font for art exhibition / photo book?

Tags: fonts

Good day.

Can you suggest me free font "suitable" for art exhibition ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I'm going to say it's not possible to make font recommendations when we can't see the layout/design. Perhaps consider sharing it.  Also font selection is entirely subjective. There's no right or wrong answer, and all you will get are opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any font on the planet can be suitable for an art exhibition... depending on what art exhibition, what is the theme of it.

Fonts are created through different periods in history. Do some research on the period of the art you are exhibiting and find a font that matches that period. Classical Rome, medieval times, renaissance, industrial era, digital era, etc.

One good place to look is google fonts. But you need to do your homework on how your font should look before diving into it.